# Apache location overlapping

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-alias

I'm trying to create an alias to intercept some url to serve from file system directly with Apache 2.4

In my virtualhost, I have: DocumentRoot */var/www/mysubroot*

I have a location on "/" in order to send all to the apache balancer

```
<Location / >
        ProxyPass balancer://my-cluster/
        ProxyPassReverse /      
        # Add the unique id on the header
        RequestHeader set UNIQUE_ID %{UNIQUE_ID}e
</Location>
```

I tried to add an alias to serve some content from the filesystem but it is never functional

```
Alias "/hidden/" "/var/www/hidden/"
<Location /hidden/ >
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</Location>
```

A call to http://myvirtualhost/hidden/mysecretfolder/test.txt is rendered by the **Location /** and not the *alias*

Any clue to how make it work (even with other solution than alias) ?

---

Also I have others *location* directives in the virtualhost and have no issue with them as they "proxy" as attended.

```
<Location /rainloop/ > 
    ProxyPass http://10.14.1.103/rainloop/
    ProxyPassReverse /rainloop/         
</Location>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact I add *ProxyPass "!"* in the location of the alias and the block need to be **after** the bloc of the *Location /*

```
Alias "/hidden/" "/var/www/hidden/"
<Location /hidden/ >
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    ProxyPass "!"
</Location>
```